# Unable to handle click events for individual buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

**What I want to do:** I have two buttons in my html client. I want to handle button click events on the server side using two different and separate event-handler functions.

I will click any button, and upon clicking, the client will send a text message to the server and the server will print it on the console using python's `print()`-function.

**What problem I am facing:** The server is printing the first message up on the first connection.

However, subsequent button clicks are not achieving the desired result. I am clicking the buttons, the server is not printing the texts sent by the client.

**How can I achieve what I am aiming for?** What am I doing incorrectly?

---

**client_sends_control_content.py**

```
# client sends,
# server receives.

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('client_sends_control_content.html')


@socketio.on('my_event1', namespace='/test')
def handle_my_event1(arg1):
    try:
        print('received_1 : ' + str(arg1['data1']))
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.exception("")
        print(ex)


@socketio.on('my_event2', namespace='/test')
def handle_my_event2(arg2):
    try:
        print('received_2 : ' + str(arg2['data2']))
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.exception("")
        print(ex)


@socketio.on('my_event3', namespace='/test')
def handle_my_event3(arg3):
    try:
        print('received_3 : ' + str(arg3['data3']))
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.exception("")
        print(ex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

**client_sends_control_content.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>click demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        let namespace = '/test';
        let socket = io(namespace);

        //connect to the server on page load
        $(function(){
            socket.on('connect', function(){
                socket.emit('my_event1', {'data1' : 'Hello World!'});
                //alert("connected!")
            });

            $('#button2').click(function(){
                socket.on('connect', function(){
                    let text2 = "2 2 2 2 2 2"
                    socket.emit('my_event2', {'data2' : text2});
                });
                //alert('btn2 clicked!')
            });

            $('#button3').click(function(){
                socket.on('connect', function(){
                    let text3 = "3 3 3 3 3 3"
                    socket.emit('my_event3', {'data3' : text3});
                });
                //alert('btn3 clicked!')
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="button2" type="button" value="Button 2">
    <input id="button3" type="button" value="Button 3">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.on('connect',` registers a callback for when the WebSocket connects from the client to the server. Registering a function to handle a click event from jQuery means that function will only be called when you click the element it is attached to. Your code registers a new callback for `connect` events when the button is pressed. But because the original `connect` event is handled already by the first callback, registering further callbacks results in nothing happening. You want to change the `on('connect1'` handler registrations within the button click handlers to just emit the message to the server.

```
            $('#button2').click(function(){
                let text2 = "2 2 2 2 2 2";
                socket.emit('my_event2', {'data2' : text2});
                //alert('btn2 clicked!')
            });
```